# Which Selenium version support OperaDriver version?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, version

I think i'm a bit confused about the version of Selenium either 2 or 3 in which supports the Opera 62 or even 63 (latest)? And inside [the main HQ Web](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) or [Github](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver) itself **doesn't telling us which version of Selenium that support for the Opera 62/63 version**?

My computer specs are:

- Windows v7 64bit
- RAM 8GB
- Netbeans v8
- Selenium v3.14
- JDK v8
- OperaDriver v75

Because many versions of OperaWebDrivers still need to be matched with the Selenium itself... otherwise it's producing error just like me:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Where is the selenium version matching to the Opera Browser docs?
2. Is it allowable to use ChromeDriver to automate Opera Browser (since
   both are chromium based?)
3. Why doesn't Selenium put the single page / docs about the version
   matching (works)?

Comment: https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/issues/71 Its known issue for latest version of Opera. For versions https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases . Use Selenium 3.141.59

Comment: i use that version, but not working as expected... is there anything i forgot?

Comment: You need to downgrade to opera 60 and use opera driver 2.45  Or wait for next release of Operadriver.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the selenium version matching to the Opera Browser docs?
 --> selenium 3.141.59 will support Opera

use operadriver v.75.0.3770.100 to support opera62
https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases/tag/v.75.0.3770.100

Is it allowable to use ChromeDriver to automate Opera Browser (since both are chromium based?)
 --> Yes since Opera is based on chromium, it is expected to get same behaviour on both chrome and opera browser. Instead of trying chromedriver for opera, it is better to test on Chrome browser itself, since it will show similar behaviour as Opera.

Comment: i did already.
I'm using the same specs, please check out my update description above.